# Should I create a new forest for the DMZ

Tags: active-directory, email, certificate, dmz

I have a local area network with a DC called "**mycompanyptyltd.local**" and a DMZ that is not in the AD DC forest.

I own the domain "**mycompany.com**" and I receive and send email from the mail server in the DMZ but cannot get SSL because the mail server is in a Workgroup rather than mycompany.com

Should I create a forest "**mycompany.com**" for the DMZ in the DC and join the mail server to it or should I install a separate domain controller, create an AD forest "**mycompany.com**" for the DMZ and then join the mail server.

Comment: No. Also `cannot get SSL because the mail server is in a Workgroup` is absurd.

Answer (score 0):

Why bother? The mail server does not have to be in a domain to be named (e.g.) `mail.mycompany.com`. You need it to have a hostname, and you need an A record in your public DNS that points to that server, but you don't need it to be in a domain. You can give it a FQDN while it's in a workgroup. There are millions of Linux machines out there that have SSL certificates that do not live in domains.